# Getting an error complaining of my array size

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, loops, size

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programming_Exercise_27 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] list1 = new int[3];
        int[] list2 = new int[3];

        System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers for list1: ");


        for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){
            list1[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers for list2: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++){
            list2[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        if(equal(list1, list2) == true){

            System.out.println("The two lists are identical");
        }

        else{

            System.out.println("The two lists are not identical");
        }
    }


    public static boolean equal(int[] list1, int[] list2){

        boolean decision = true;
        int hold;
        int check = 0;
        int check2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++){

            hold = list1[i];

            for (int x = 0; i < list1.length; x++){

                if (list1[x] == hold){

                    check++;
                }
                else { /* do nothing */ }

            }

            for (int y = 0; i < list2.length; y++){

                if (list2[y] == hold){

                    check2++;
                }
                else{ /* do nothing */ }

            }

            if (check != check2){

                decision = false;
                break;
            }
            else{

                check = 0;
                check2 = 0;
                hold = 0;
            }
        }


        return decision;
    }


}
```

What I am trying to do is have my equal method to count the occurrence of a certain number in the array. If each number of numbers is equal in the arrays that means they are identical. But for some reason I keep running into an array size problem. Please help.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: "an array size problem" really doesn't explain much about the problem - do you get an exception? If so, where? It would also be easier to reproduce the problem if you got rid of the section asking for input from the user - just hard-code an example where it fails, and that will get rid of half the code...

Comment: Please include the actual error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
for (int x = 0; i < list1.length; x++){
```

should have `x` instead of `i` in the condition, otherwise `x` will just keep on increasing, until `list1[x]` runs off the end of the array.  Likewise, this line

```
for (int y = 0; i < list2.length; y++){
```

should have `y` instead of `i`.

Comment: What a great eye. Thank you this is what made the code successful!

Comment: @user2991463: Please learn from this that you should improve on your question asking skills as well. Your question was very unclear, with an incredibly vague description of the problem you were encountering - please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list